# Accessing VirtualBox share from IIS

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, network-share, virtualbox, iis-8.5

I'm trying to have IIS 8.5 access a VirtualBox shared folder.

The physical path for the website was changed to `\\VBOXSVR\application`. Now, when I open localhost, I get the following error message:

HTTP Error 500.19 Internal Server Error
Cannot read configuration file.

I assume that IIS does not have the permissions to access the network share, is that right? How can I correct that problem?

Comment: Hello, VirtualBox is not a production-worth virtualization system. I'd recommend you consider VMware vSphere or Hyper-V instead.

Comment: Still, VMware vSphere uses shared network folders too. How do I get IIS to access these folders correctly?